# How I do update winrt core libs?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cli

I have on my pc windows 8.1 and VCCORLIB120_APP.DLL version - VCLibs.120.00_12.0.20812.1. How I do update libs to new version VCLibs.120.00_12.0.21005.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either by installing the newest version of the Windows SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx or by installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 4: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2994375